# How to use nested rules in less?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to customize bootstrap styles for my needs. I use LESS. I have a table with the table-hover class. I need to add an extra behaviour to the hover effect. I want to add visible (left) border to a row when it is hovered. I took the standard bootstrap rule and nested an additional styles inside:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > th {
background-color: #f5f5f5;

tr {
    border-left: 4px;
    border-left-color: @active-element-color;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Your goal really isn't clear.

Comment: I have a table. I added a bootstrap class to it called table-hover. It changes (slightly) the color of hovered row. In addidtion I want to add to hovered row a vertical line (additional indication of hovered row like on the bootstrap website the navigation menu has vertical position indicator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the right order for nested rules :

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr {
    /* Match every <tr> in a .table-hover */
    border-left: 4px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-left-style: solid;

    &:hover {
        /* Match hover stats for these <tr> */
        border-left-color: @active-element-color;

        > th, 
        > td {
            /* Match <th> and <td> for hovered <tr> */
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
    }
}
```

In your example you were trying to target `.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > th tr` :

```
<table class="table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- :hover -->
            <th>
                <tr><!-- Targeted element --></tr>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In this case all my rows have the left visible border (I do not need even hover them).

Comment: Ok, didn't get you only wanted it on `:hover`. I edited my post.

Comment: Yes. Now it is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. So my fault was in the wrong order of the nesting?

Comment: Yes. You were targeting a `<tr>` **inside** a `<th>` / `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your intent but it looks like you want this :

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-left-color: @active-element-color;
    border-left-style: solid;
    & > th, & > td {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this doesn't add the left border to the row.